# C4d to blender?

Tags: python, animation, mesh, materials, armature

this is my first post/question and I wanted to see if there is some plugin/way that I don't know of to get a c4d file to import to Blender or to convert c4d files to fbx without cinema 4d. If there is no current way to do so, who would like to team up with me to create a plugin to import c4d file contents into blender??

Hope someone can help me with this, Thanks for reading this regardless of if you can help or not ^^

Comment: Alembic is your best bet for now, also USD is on its way being part of any 3d package so you just have to wait for it. Otherwise I personally see no chance without using cinema because c4d files are binaries.